# How to resize a text field in order to remove scrolling on an onload event?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I deal with dynamics CRM 2011 online and I faced some troubles with printing documents there.

Could I resize/expand a text field in order to make a text visible for user without any scrolling?

Has anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a supported fashion.

[Supported Extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx)

> Form Scripting
>
> Microsoft JScript functions that are associated through the
>   customization tools to the available events in the form are supported.
>   Interaction with data in the form is supported when performed using
>   documented objects and methods available within the Xrm.Page.data
>   object. Interaction with the form appearance and behavior is supported
>   when performed using documented objects and methods available within
>   the Xrm.Page.ui object. However, any direct interaction with the HTML
>   Document Object Model (DOM) will probably not be upgradable. The
>   structure of forms and HTML elements used in the forms could change in
>   future releases. For more information, see Write Code for Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM Forms.

And as far as I know Xrm.Page.ui doesn't support that kind of functionality.